# Connecting database (user table) with Java

Tags: java, database, authentication

I got this login form using `java.swing` and now I want to connect my login to a table that is, user details (username and password) should all be stored on a local database for login process.I tried creating a table with access then connecting it but I am missing the "System DNS" drivers.

I do not have any actual code for my database connection since I feel its better to ask the best simplest way to do it since I am really getting confused and doesn't work when I tried.

In the end, my questions are : is it possible to create a database (like in visual studio) in eclipse? What is the correct and simpler way? Would it be better to create a different class rather than cramming it up in the login page code? If yes, how do you actually connect both pages?

```
public class Loginpage 
{

private JFrame frmGooglePlusExtractor;
private JTextField usernametxt;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

/**
 * Launches the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Loginpage window = new Loginpage();
                window.frmGooglePlusExtractor.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Loginpage() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialise the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmGooglePlusExtractor = new JFrame();
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.setResizable(false);
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.setTitle("Google Plus Extractor");
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.setBounds(100, 100, 326, 200);
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frmGooglePlusExtractor.getContentPane().add(panel);

    usernametxt = new JTextField();
    usernametxt.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblPassword.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton btnLogIn = new JButton("Log In");
    btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            loginmsg dlg = new loginmsg();

            dlg.setVisible(true);
            frmGooglePlusExtractor.setVisible(false);   

        }
    });
    btnLogIn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    final JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Quit");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals(btnCancel));
            {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to leave?");

            frmGooglePlusExtractor.dispose();

            }


        }
    });
    btnCancel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();

    btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        }
}
```

However, I tried the following before but could not get it work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection cnctn;

    try{

        // load jdbc driver
        String driver = "com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver";

        Class.forName(driver);

        //create connection

        String server = "localhost";
        String port = "55555";
        String database  = server + port;
        String url = "jdbc:JSQLConnect://" + database;
        String username = "username";
        String password  = "password";

        try {
            cnctn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("could not connect");
        }

    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {

        System.out.println("could not find db");
    }

}
```

Comment: You dont have any of your code for connecting to the database.

Comment: That's because I don't really know how to do it. So I am asking the simplest way to do, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I added some code which I tried but could not get it working @user489041

Answer (score 0):

Most of url's (or all of them) use colon to separe server and port number in this way: `server:port`.
Database should be an actual database name (that you have on your server). So in most of times url should look like:

`String url="jdbc:JSQLConnect://"+server+":"+port+"/"+databaseName;`

And just for the record last catch clause and its exception informs that it couldnt find driver, not database.

Comment: Do you know where can I get mysql-connector-java-4.0.0-bin.jar,please? Seems I am missing that file and this is needed for the db connection.

Comment: tried to paste lmgtfu link... just type "jdbc mysql connector jar download" in google, does others have to think for you?